# Difficulty with tweeting in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Write a function named "tweets" that takes a string as a parameter and returns the number of tweets required to tweet the input to the world. Note: The maximum length for a single tweet is 280 characters

```
 function tweets(x) {
    if (x.length <= 280) {
    return 1;
    }
    else {
    return false;
    }
 }
```

I keep getting a incorrect input when running my code. How should I fix my code?

Comment: What kind of inputs you are getting? Could you be precise?

Comment: Are you sure your question says _"returns the number of **tweets** required"_? Should it not be _"characters"_? In any case, you are returning either the number `1` or Boolean `false`. That does not sound like it matches the requirements

Comment: A person is only able to send one message containing 280 characters. If he/she wanted to send two messages they would have to write 560 characters... So for this problem, you want to return the number of messages a person can send based on whatever number of characters he/she writes.

 

Test cases:

tweets(280) => 1

tweets(560) => 2

Comment: Ah right, thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you want to divide the total of characters (the `length` of then string) by 280, and the round to the next bigger integer (with `Math.ceil()`).

You can use something like : `let numOfTweetsNeeded = Math.ceil(x.length / 280);`

Why we are doing a division part should become "obvious" with your test cases :

- 280 is 280 * 1
- 560 is 280 * 2

Now, let's say you have 281 characters, then the division will give a decimal number between 1 and 2 (1.00357... actually). So the important part is that it won't fit in 1 tweet exactly, so you must use another just for this 1 excess character

Comment: Do you need to account for adding `1/`, `2/`, etc ;)

Comment: This part wasn't stated by OP. Actually, I think OP struggled already to get the basic principle, so my answer don't account for that.

Comment: Sorry if it wasn't obvious but I was only half-joking (though adding a number prefix would be a nifty extension to this problem)

Comment: Ha ! Was about to say "you should write a smiley in this case ;) " but you actually did, I just somehow didn't see it.

Comment: I should have added a nose, or used an emoji 